# What is wrong with this sentence? A dangling participle? A missed modifier? HELP!

Tags: dangling-participles

This sentence has me stumped. I know there's something wrong with it but I can't put my finger on it.  The sentence is:

> Because artificial sweeteners are more addictive than regular sugar, people who drink diet sodas consume twice as much as regular soda drinkers.

I know the sentence is incomplete in some way because it is not saying what they consume more--diet soda or food in general, but is that a participle missing or something else? It might be helpful to know that this is in regards to weight loss and the fact that diet soda doesn't help as promised.

Comment: You feel the participle of Damocles hanging over your head, do you?

Comment: (The word that's "missing" is *soda*.)

Comment: Now, the sentence is fine.

Comment: "Because artificial sweeteners are more addictive than regular sugar, people who drink diet sodas consume twice as much ***dinosaur meat*** as regular soda drinkers." Obviously.

Comment: Obviously, they should switch from soda to pop. That will make everything better.  If it’s too abrupt a change, they can drink soda-pop during the transition period.

Comment: The sentence is missing a full stop. "Because artificial sweeteners are more addictive than regular sugar, people who drink diet sodas consume twice as much." Also, when did diet soda promise you something?

Comment: @Hot Licks, thank you for your concise response.   - PEACE -

Answer (score 1):

All joking aside, there is really enough context that the reader is highly unlikely to conclude you meant anything other than soda. The sentence is fine, as Greg Lee said.

But if you want to be 100% unambiguous, you could insert "soda" after "much", as Hot Licks suggested.

Or if you really didn't mean soda, say "food", or "calories", or whatever they did consume twice as much of.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful response.  @Iam MacDonald, although this is an essay on veganism, I appreciate your answer too.  You're all correct, of course, the missing word makes the difference.  Still don't know if it's a dangling participle or not but I'll do a bit more research on the subject.  In the meantime, thank you all for your insights. -PEACE-

Comment: You're welcome, kind lady.